# Dynamically reduce the number of months stored in the table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have MONTH1 and MONTH2 tables that I am using to build a query. In the final output, I need to have 12 months of retention. Currently, the MONTH2 table is empty, but the data will be added every month. My idea is to UNION the queries and set a rule that with each month, one less month of data is taken from MONTH1. As a result, the final output should have a year of data that comes partially from MONTH 1 and partially from MONTH2. Once MONTH2 has 12 months of data, the query using MONTH1 should stop adding rows.

The query is the following:

```
SELECT
MONTH,
COUNTRY_NAME,
WEBSITE

FROM MONTH1

GROUP BY 1,2,3

UNION ALL 

SELECT
MONTH,
COUNTRY_NAME,
WEBSITE

FROM MONTH2

GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

What would be a good method to achieve this?

Comment: First query needs a subquery Where clause - include only the dates not in Month2: `Where Month not in (Select month from month2)`

Comment: Can you send us some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Note that using UNION ALL will also produce duplicates that exist in both data sets.  I agree you should likely be using the MONTH2 in a subquery called from the first query's WHERE clause, but would like to see sample data and expected results to confirm approach.